# One who moves without legs

Tags: riddle

Moving without legs, you have seen me.
 I do roar sometimes but have no mouth.
 Sometimes I cry too but have no eyes.

Who / What am I?

Comment: Welcome to the Puzzling SE! I suggest looking at the [editing help](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if you want to learn something about how formatting works, since it might be kinda tricky to begin with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer is

> cloud

roar

> thunder

cry

> rain

Comment: it is quick answer... right one

Comment: @Premalatha to be precise, my answer was 8 seconds faster, but if the answer is a cloud, I'm wrong anyways ;)

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> the wind / a storm?

Moving without legs, you have seen me

> its air in movement

I do roar sometimes but have no mouth.

> thunder?

Sometimes cry too but have no eyes.

> rain?